# What is the general solution of the differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The given equation is  $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=f(x)$. 
I know that the C.F. is $~a\sin{x}+b\cos{x}$ but i stuck on P.I.. For non-homogeneous eautions, the theorem stating the methods to find P.I.s are not helpful for me in this case. The answer given is $~y(x)=a\sin{x}+b\cos{x}+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\sin{(x-t)}dt$. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it really $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$ shouldn't it be $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$?

Comment: Sorry typo. Edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have probably used the following general result (which I state without giving any conditions):

> **Theorem** If $Y$ is a solution to the  homogeneous differential equation
>   $$
> y''(x)+y(x)=0
> $$
>   with conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$. Then the function
>   $$
> u(x)=\int_0^x Y(x-t)f(t)\,dt
> $$
>   is a solution to
>   $$
> y''(x)+y(x)=f(x).
> $$
>   Moreover, it satisfies $u(0)=0$ and $u'(0)=0$.

This is typically shown by differentiating under the integral sign, and is a good exercise.

In your case $Y(x)=\sin x$ satisfies $Y''+Y=0$ and $Y(0)=0$ and $Y'(0)=1$.

**A final comment**: The theorem above is more general. It holds for general linear differential equations, and not only those with $y''+y$ in the left-hand side.

Comment: The idea of this theorem is that the solution to $y''+y=0,y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$ can also be viewed as the solution to $y''+y=\delta,y(0)=0,y'(0)=0$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta. (The second derivative being a Dirac delta corresponds to a jump in the first derivative.) Thus $Y$ is the Green's function of the operator $Ly=y''+y$, so that $f = \delta * f = LY * f = L(Y * f)$, where $*$ denotes convolution.

Comment: Good comment, @Ian. I was aware of this, and I should have put a name on it.

Answer (score 1):

Let us condider $y_h$ as the homogenous solution to your ODE. In order to find the particular solution you will have to plug in

$$y=c(x)y_h=c(x)[a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)]$$ into your ODE. Then solve for $c(x)$ and resubstitute into $y$ to get your general solution.

Comment: c(x) is a function of x so while putting it in the DE, i have to differentiate it w.r.t x also right?